# Convergence in $D'$

Tags: distribution-theory

I was given by my professor of mathematical methods for physicist, a notion of convergence in $D'(\Omega)$, the space of distributions on $D(\Omega)$.
Namely:

A sequence of distributions $T_n\in\ D'(\Omega)$ is said to converge to a distribution in $D'(\Omega)$ if $\forall \phi \in D(\Omega)$ $<T_n,\phi>\rightarrow<T,\phi>$.

My question is: in what ways is this notion of convergence meaningful? Is it induced by a norm? If not, why have we chosen this particular notion of convergence?

Is it because it makes the space "complete"? What does it even mean, without a metric (if there isn't one, obviously), to be complete?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $D'(\Omega)$ is complete but not induced by a norm, basically you have a bunch of seminorms; it is (what is known) as a LF space. A more conceptual viewpoint on the topology on $D'(\Omega)$ is that it is a certain locally convex direct limit of spaces $C^\infty_0(\Omega')$. A good reference for the general framework is Bourbaki's *espaces vectoriels topologiques*, chapitre II, §4. espaces localement convexes; or Simon/Reed, functional analysis, chapter 4.

Comment: Attention: $\mathcal{D}'$ with either weak or strong topology is NOT metrizable, so it is NOT a Frechet space! It is a complete space as a uniform space.

Comment: @Vobo: thanks, you are right. I now gave the correct terminology.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [the wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29) on distributions is a good source to start with.

This type of convergence is called the weak-* convergence - more on it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology).

The space of distributions is complete under this notion of convergence, but this space is not normed. It is a locally convex space. It is a multinormed space.

For a topological space to be complete means that every Cauchy net (generalisation of Cauchy sequence) has a limit.